# How to play video in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I used both video component

```java
Video video = new Video();
```

and embedded

```java
Embedded embed = new Embedded("my video", new ExternalResource("yyy/xxx.mp4")); 
embed.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
```

This plays quite well in iphone which uses safari browser, but in my pc am using mozilla firefox browser its not playing.

It shows an like error in mime type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check this code from vaadin sampler :

```
Embedded e = new Embedded(null, new ExternalResource(
            "http://www.youtube.com/v/meXvxkn1Y_8&hl=en_US&fs=1&"));
    e.setAlternateText("Vaadin Eclipse Quickstart video");
    e.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
    e.setParameter("allowFullScreen", "true");
    e.setWidth("320px");
    e.setHeight("265px");
    addComponent(e);
```

It works for me both chrome and firefox. I think your firefox addons may cause this problem.